# Magento 2 admin is not working?

Tags: url, magento2.2.2, admin-panel

I am using magento 2.2.2

Frontend is working fine but admin is not working.

I have tried to deploy, upgrade, cache, compile etc but the admin is not working.

The admin url  is strange:

http://example.ca/admin/admin/admin/admin/index/index/key/16a571c82b097532a0b0a544997cf996979213e762894a777ddb798c5f476ad6/?SID=aiu8b9j92on4tv3m1thgsr8ub6

So normally admin keyword comes 2 times in the url but in my case it is coming 4 times.

I have check `core_config_data` table where `custom_url` and `custom_path` is set to `0`.

Comment: Do you see any error when you try to access the admin panel?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, no error is showing.

Comment: have you try to open admin URL in private browser?

Comment: many times tried.

Comment: Do you have any solution to this? I am seeing this same error in 2.4.3 the URL had admin/admin/admin/admin.